# Elasticsearch - terms lookup - filter

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl, elasticsearch-query

I have two indices: `users` and `cars`

`users` contains `user_id` and car `ratings` of the user.
`ratings` objects represent car ratings (by the user)

```
"user_id": 3,
"ratings": [
    {
        "score": 10.0,
        "car_id": "xxx"
    },                    
    {
        "score": 50.0,
        "car_id": "yyy"
    }
  ]
```

I'm trying to build a query that fetches cars, rated by user 3 with score higher than 20.

That means, the query would return "yyy" car only (based on the document above) as user 3 has two ratings, but only of them has score greater than 20.

I've managed to build a query that returns all cars rated by a given user.

```
GET _search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "terms": {
            "car_id": {
              "index": "users",
              "type": "_doc",
              "id": "3",
              "path": "ratings.car_id"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

The problem is that I can't figure out how to filter ratings by the `ratings.score`.

This query is not returning any car even if there are two cars rated by the user `3` with score greater than `20`:

```
GET _search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "terms": {
            "car_id": {
              "index": "users",
              "type": "_doc",
              "id": "3",
              "path": "ratings.car_id"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "range": {
            "ratings.score": {
              "gte": 20
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Can you tell me what's wrong and how to make it work?

---

**MAPPINGS**

`users`

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "_doc": {
      "properties": {
        "ratings": {
          "type": "nested",
          "properties": {
            "car_id": {
              "type": "text"
            },
            "score": {
              "type": "float"
            },
            "type": {
              "type": "text",
              "fields": {
                "keyword": {
                  "type": "keyword",
                  "ignore_above": 256
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "user_id": {
          "type": "integer"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

`cars`

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "_doc": {
      "properties": {
        "name": {
          "type": "text"
        },
        "color": {
          "type": "boolean"
        },
....
```

Answer (score 0):

The field "ratings" is nested. Recommend use [Nested Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-nested-query.html).

I couldnt test this query:

```
"filter": [
    {
      "terms": {
        "car_id": {
          "index": "users",
          "id": "3",
          "path": "user_id"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "nested": {
        "path": "ratings",
        "query": {
          "range": {
            "ratings.score": {
              "gte": 20
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ]
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on that? How to use it with another index? Thanks

Comment: Thank you, in fact, I think I tried already this query (once again now). It returns `failed to create query: [nested] failed to find nested object under path [ratings]` - it's good to add that the `terms` block is slightly different. The path is "ratings.car_id" instead of "user_id", but the "nested" block is the same.